# Inserting line breaks between/before/after tables

Tags: openoffice-writer

If you make a table at the very beginning of a document or a table right after another table. There doesn't seem to be any way of getting your cursor before/after this table? It seems like it's then impossible to insert any content here?? Does anyone know how to solve this? Or is this a bug (bad feature)??

I've resorted many times to throwing away these documents and start from scratch and never ever do this. To ALWAYS leave a blank line between tables or if nothing is before an empty line...

Edit: You can select all table rows and copy paste them into the new document to save time but this is still an awkward hack and steals time!

Can this be solved in less hacked way?

Answer (score 14):

In LibreOffice Writer 4.2.6.3, if you need to add a line before a table, put the cursor at the beginning of the top left cell and press Alt-Enter (not just Enter, as advised in other posts -- that doesn't work). If you need a new line after a table, put the cursor at the end of the bottom right cell and press Alt-Enter.

The same procedure works if you have formatted a part of the document with multiple columns. To add a line before the multi-column section, put the cursor at the beginning of the first paragraph in the multi-column section and press Alt-Enter. To add a line after the multi-column section put the cursor at the end of the last paragraph in that section and press Alt-Enter.

Comment: This works for me. I'm surprised I'm the first to upvote it. If this answer helps you solve the problem, please vote for it!

Comment: Question is about Open Office Writer, not LibreOffice...

Answer (score 3):

I just tried to place the cursor at the beginning of the first cell, and pressed enter in LibreOffice Writer, and it worked splendidly. I tried it before, and it didn't work. Then I right-clicked and unchecked the table **Table boundaries** and it worked.

Now having the boundaries checked makes no difference.

Comment: Indeed, having the boundaries checked or unchecked makes no difference.

Comment: Question is about Open Office Writer, not LibreOffice...

Answer (score 1):

To get in front of a table, cursor in top left cell and press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
To get behind a table, cursor in bottom right cell and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice 4.3.0.4:

To move the cursor to a new blank line following a table, you must first place your cursor at the end of any data in the last cell on the last row of the table, hold Alt, and press Enter.

Comment: Question is about Open Office Writer, not LibreOffice...