# libreoffice writer - default spacing between sections

Tags: libreoffice

When I write libreoffice docs (.odt files) I usually like to organize content into separate sections (Insert -> Section).

I also would like to leave a minimum space of one line between each others. If accidentally I don't leave this space, I cannot position the cursor between them to separate manually with a new line.

Is it possible to leave a default spacing between sections ?
If so, how ? I did not find any format setting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [tables](https://superuser.com/questions/515054/inserting-line-breaks-between-before-after-tables), to add a line break before a section, place the cursor at the very beginning of the section and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: without line breaks]

Now there is a line break in between the two sections.

[image: now has a line break]